# Java String.join but also add delimiter to the end

Tags: java, string

I have the array `["a", "b", "c"]` and I want to join them together to form "a#b#c#". String.join will only get me "a#b#c". I can't just do `str += "#"` either because that is slow (Java has to create a new string to do that). So instead I have to rewrite the whole thing using `StringBuilder`. Is there some method Java has that is basically String.join but also appends the delimiter to the end?

For a little more context, I'm trying to create a Suffix Array data structure with a group of strings, so this part of it is actually a bottleneck.

Comment: Can you add an empty string `""` to the end of the array and then call `join`?

Comment: @WanderNauta Isn't the performance impact of copying the array to add an element likely higher than just adding another character to the string after joining?

Comment: "I can't just do `str += "#"` either because that is slow.". It's not *that* slow.

Comment: Wander Nauta is right adding empty string to the end will get you the expected output

Comment: Chances are that the compiler will optimize `str += "#"` to use a `StringBuilder`, if it is believed to be faster...

Comment: @Kayaman To be honest it wouldn't even be slow to do str += "#" since its O(N) and Suffix Array build is O(N log N), but it just bugs me for some reason, so I was wondering if there was a better way

Comment: @WillKanga I measured the performance of the 3 solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68424182/5024726

Answer (score 11):

You can use Stream API Collectors.joining() There are prefix and suffix arguments like that:

```
    Stream.of("a", "b", "c")
        .collect(Collectors.joining("#", "", "#"));
```

Where joining arguments is delimiter, prefix, suffix respectively.

Also, you can just add an empty String to your array like says  @Wander Nauta in the comment above

I've started JMH, also and reproduce performance differences which wrote
[bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68424182/14927001):

```
public class Benchmarks {

private static final String[] arr = {"a", "b", "c"};

@Benchmark
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Fork(value = 1, warmups = 1)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
public String joinAndConcat() {
    return String.join("#", arr) + "#";
}

@Benchmark
@Fork(value = 1, warmups = 1)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
public String streamsJoining() {
    return Stream.of(arr)
            .parallel()
            .collect(Collectors.joining("#", "", "#"));
}

@Benchmark
@Fork(value = 1, warmups = 1)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
public String stringJoiner() {
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("#", "", "#");
    for (String el : arr) {
        joiner.add(el);
    }
    return joiner.toString();
  }
}
```

Results:

```
> Benchmark                  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
> Benchmarks.joinAndConcat   avgt    5  46,670 ± 0,139  ns/op
> Benchmarks.streamsJoining  avgt    5  73,336 ± 0,180  ns/op
> Benchmarks.stringJoiner    avgt    5  27,236 ± 0,386  ns/op
```

But you must understand that 46 `nSec` is a very small difference for most applications.

Comment: I like this solution but if OP is worried that `+=` is slow than I'd assume Stream with a collector is too slow as well.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki what do you think the collector uses internally? It's effectively just the same as your answer.

Comment: I'd imagine that creating a Stream pipeline, even with just a single collector, out of an array will be more expensive than `+=`.

Comment: I'm sure this isn't a real problem for modern jdk, because there are a lot of byte code optimizations, such as using StringBuilder instead concatenation operator

Comment: You can use JMH and show us results with collector and without, I'm not sure about big difference

Comment: @DmitriiBykov the same approach could/should be taken for straight concatenation, of course.

Comment: @DmitriiBykov I measured the performance of the 3 solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68424182/5024726

Answer (score 5):

Here are the performance measures using [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/):

```
Benchmark       Mode   Cnt         Score        Error  Units
StringJoiner    thrpt  100  23641181.522 ± 237176.955  ops/s
JoinAndConcat   thrpt  100  14197523.377 ± 130873.538  ops/s
StreamsJoining  thrpt  100   9538282.522 ± 156729.920  ops/s
```

The [solution with streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68423618/5024726) takes around **2.5x** longer compared to the [solution with `StringJoiner`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68423621/5024726). In the midfield is as expected the join with concatenation (see question). However, we are talking about nanoseconds here.

*A graphical overview showing the performance with recalculated values (`ops/s => ns/op`):*
[image: result]

---

```
# JMH version: 1.32
# VM version: JDK 11.0.11, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 11.0.11+9
# VM invoker: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
# VM options: <none>
# Blackhole mode: full + dont-inline hint
# Warmup: 10 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 10 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
```

```java
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;

public class Benchmarks {

    private static final String[] arr = {"a", "b", "c"};

    @Benchmark
    public String joinAndConcat() {
        return String.join("#", arr) + "#";
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String streamsJoining() {
        return Stream.of(arr)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("#", "", "#"));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String stringJoiner() {
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("#", "", "#");
        for (String el : arr) {
            joiner.add(el);
        }
        return joiner.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`String.join()` uses `StringJoiner` behind the scenes so you can create one and specify `suffix` parameter as `#` in the constructor:

```
String[] array = { "a", "b", "c" };
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("#", "", "#");
for (String el : array) {
  joiner.add(el);
}
System.out.println(joiner.toString()); // a#b#c#
```

However this feels like micro optimizing. Unless your joining code is critical it's way more readable to write:

```
String[] array = { "a", "b", "c" };
System.out.println(String.join("#", array) + "#"); // a#b#c#
```

Comment: I measured the performance of the 3 solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68424182/5024726